# prestashop module => how to reach values from config.xml file

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am beginning with Prestashop 1.7.

My questions are: how to reach and use the data in `config.xml` in the code if it cannot be done through `Configuration::get('[something in the config.xml file]')`? And why properties not filled out in the `__construct()` of the custom module (like: `$this->name`, `$this->tab`, `$this->description`, `$this->confirmUninstall`) are not automatically substitued with the equivalent values from the `config.xml` file?

**Here is what I have tried:**

I ve been looking at [Creation a PrestaShop 1.7 Module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Creating+a+PrestaShop+1.7+Module);

I've been going through:

1. What is a PrestaShop module?
2. Creating a first module
3. About the config.xml file
4. Adding a configuration page

I experienced how to set up the configuration by playing around with the functions `getContent()` and `displayForm()`.

But I don't understand how to reach data from the `config.xml` file.

My `config.xml` file is like that (in directory `[PrestashopProject]\module`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<module>
  <name>mymodule</name>
  <displayName><![CDATA[My module]]></displayName>
  <version><![CDATA[1.0]]></version>
  <description><![CDATA[Description of my module.]]></description>
  <author><![CDATA[Firstname Lastname]]></author>
  <tab><![CDATA[front_office_features]]></tab>
  <confirmUninstall>Are you sure you want to uninstall?</confirmUninstall>
  <is_configurable>1</is_configurable>
  <need_instance>0</need_instance>
  <limited_countries>fr</limited_countries>
</module>
```

I have my files `mymodule.php` (which is also in the directory `[PrestashopProject]\module`) looking as describe in the guide:

```
class mymodule extends Module {
    public function __construct(){
    $this->name = 'mymodule';
     ...
    $this->bootstrap = false;
     parent::__construct();
    $this->displayName = $this->l('My Module');

     ....
    if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME')) $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided.');

    }

    public function install(){
     ...
     return true;
   }

    public function uninstall(){
     ...      
     return true;
    }
    public function getContent(){
      ....//stuff to manage the submit of the form designed for configuration settings


    }

    public function displayForm(){
      ....//
      $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            ), 
            'input' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                'name' => 'confirmUninstall',
                'size' => 20,
                'required' => true
           ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
            )
        );
        $helper = new HelperForm();
        .... // stuff with $helper like in the doc


        $helper->fields_value['confirmUninstall'] = Configuration::get('confirmUninstall');


    }
}
```

I don't get why `Configuration::get('confirmUninstall')` which is at the end of my `displayForm()` function does not display `<confirmUninstall>Are you sure you want to uninstall?</confirmUninstall>` which is in my `config.xml` file.

Also in the `__construct()` function of `class mymodule extends Module`, I could expect that if I don't add `$this->author = "[author name]";` or      `$this->displayName = $this->l('My Module');` it should pick up the data from the `config.xml` file matching tags and it does not do so.

**Following first answer I got from @TheDrot:**

I'd like to understand what I'm missing here. At the very bottom of [Creating a first module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Creating+a+first+module) it is written:

> During the module’s installation, PrestaShop automatically creates a small config.xml file in the module’s folder, which stores the configuration information. You should be very careful when editing by hand.

It is true, that at first,I've created the `config.xml` file manually because I did not see it pop up initialy.

Now whith the answer I got from @TheDrot, I've deleted my `config.xml` file, uninstalled mymodule from the Prestashop admin dashboard and re-installed it.

I thought that re-installing it would create the `config.xml` file as it should be according to `mymodule.php`. But it did not, do I miss a setting?

**UPDATE**:

It ended up creating the `config.xml` file. I don't know which action triggered it but it did. And the `config.xml` file content that has been automaticaly created matches with `mymodule.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config.xml is useless to you since it's auto generated and as said in docs used for optimizing loading of module list in backend.

Which is why you need define these options in module constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
    ...
    $this->confirmUninstall = 'Are you sure?';
    ...
}
```

And use it in `displayForm()`

```
$helper->fields_value['confirmUninstall'] = $this->confirmUninstall;
```

`Configuration::get()` has nothing to do with config.xml as it reads a value of a string in database table `dbprefix_configuration`.

Eg. to get default shop language ID:

```
$defaultLangID = Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'):
```

Comment: thanks but before I validate, I added additional question about `config.xml` file at the bottom of the original question. I don't see the `config.xml` file generating automatically.

Comment: @nyluje config.xml should get regenerated when you load modules list in backoffice. At least it does that in 1.6, maybe they changed it in 1.7 but I doubt it.

Comment: it did in the end and the content of `config.xml` matches `mymodule.php` data in the `__construct()`. Thanks for your input, I validate and vote up!